Computing expectation under change of random variable
I am following the work from Kingma and Welling, where they introduce Variational Autoencoders. To train such models they use the so called Evidence Lower Bound and maximize it. One way to solve this optimization problem is by a gradient descent method, but to do so it is required to compute (or at least estimate) the gradients of the ELBO. One of the steps of the prove requires using a "reparameterization trick" to easily compute the gradient.
My problem reduces to prove the following identity of the expectation under change of variable:
$$\mathbb{E}^{q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x})}[f(\textbf{z})] = \mathbb{E}^{p(\epsilon)}[f(g(\epsilon, \phi, \textbf{x}))]$$
with $\textbf{z} = g(\textbf{x},\epsilon,\phi)$, with $g$ differentiable and invertible, is a change of random variable between $\textbf{z} \sim q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x})$ and $\epsilon \sim p(\epsilon)$. Although I know this can be proved for a quite general function, in this case, function $f$ is $f(\textbf{z}) = \log p_\theta(\textbf{x},\textbf{z}) - \log q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x})$, where $p_\theta$ parameterizes the joint distribution between $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{z}$, and $q_\phi$ approximates a posterior distribution. So, both are parameterized density functions.
My attempt tries to use the integration under change of variables theorem, and I struggle on how to properly apply it:
$$ \mathbb{E}^{q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x})}[f(\textbf{z})] = \int_{Z|X}q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x})f(\textbf{z})d\textbf{z} =$$
$$ = \int_? q_\phi(g(\textbf{x},\epsilon,\phi)|\textbf{x})f(g(\textbf{x},\epsilon,\phi))|\nabla_\epsilon g(\textbf{x},\epsilon,\phi)|d\epsilon = ?$$
$$ ? = \mathbb{E}^{p(\epsilon)}[f(g(\epsilon, \phi, \textbf{x}))]$$
I have seen similar posts where they claim this can be proven by a direct application of LOTUS theorem, where $\mathbb{E}^p(h(u)) = \int_A p(x)h(x)dx$. They say that we can apply LOTUS to both expectations and see they are the same thing:
$$ \mathbb{E}^{q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x})}[f(\textbf{z})] = \int_{Z|X}q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x})f(\textbf{z})d\textbf{z} $$
$$ \mathbb{E}^{p(\epsilon)}[f(g(\epsilon, \phi, \textbf{x}))] = \int_{\mathcal{E}}p(\epsilon)f(g(\epsilon, \phi, \textbf{x}))d\epsilon $$
If we apply $\textbf{z} = g(\textbf{x},\epsilon,\phi)$ in the second expectation:
$$ \mathbb{E}^{p(\epsilon)}[f(g(\epsilon, \phi, \textbf{x}))] = \int_{\mathcal{g^{-1}(E)}}p(g^{-1}(\epsilon))f(\textbf{z})\frac{d\textbf{z}}{\nabla_\epsilon g(\textbf{x},\epsilon,\phi)} $$
But how is it that $q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x}) = \frac{p(g^{-1}(\epsilon))}{\nabla_\epsilon g(\textbf{x},\epsilon,\phi)}$?
I have seen many posts on ELBO but all seem to skip details like this. I would appreciate any insights on the topic.
Thank you.
